# Add event responders to elements in a loop with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Lets say I have a page with 5 images, and I get an array of them all by

```
var images = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
```

Then I want to add a mousemove event to each one, my first instinct would be to do this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++){
    $(images[i]).mousemove(function(e){
        //do stuff
    });
}
```

but that doesn't work, so how would this be possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('img').mousemove(function(){
    //do stuff
});
```

Comment: i tried this, but it didn't work because of another issue, fixed the other issue and now this is functional.